# Make class extend multiple function type interfaces with the same signature in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I want to make a class extend multiple function type interfaces.

This works since the function types have different signatures, `() -> Unit` and `(String) - Unit`

```
typealias A = () -> Unit
typealias B = (something: String) -> Unit

class Test : A, B {

    override fun invoke() {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun invoke(something: String) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

}
```

Now if I add a third function type, the compiler complains about `Conflicting Overloads` or `A supertype appears twice`

```
typealias A = () -> Unit
typealias B = (something: String) -> Unit
typealias C = (somethingElse: String) -> Unit

class Test : A, B, C {

    override fun invoke() {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun invoke(something: String) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun invoke(somethingElse: String) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
    
}
```

I can obviously go and add garbage params to `C` to make it work, but this seems more like a hack

```
typealias C = (somethingElse: String, garbage: Unit?) -> Unit
```

but now if I define type D with the same signature,

```
typealias D = (somethingElseElse: String, garbage: Unit?) -> Unit
```

I would run into the same issue.

I thought that maybe value classes could help here:

```
@JvmInline
value class BString(val value: String)

@JvmInline
value class CString(val value: String)

typealias A = () -> Unit
typealias B = (something: BString) -> Unit
typealias C = (somethingElse: CString) -> Unit

class Test : A, B, C {
    override fun invoke() {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun invoke(something: BString) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun invoke(somethingElse: CString) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

}
```

... but since value classes are compiled out of existence, that too is not a solution

> Platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same
> JVM signature (invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;):

I'm assuming Kotlin KEEP 302, Binary Signature Name (https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/binary-signature/proposals/multiplatform/binary-signature.md), would solve this issue in the future, but what is the correct way in the meantime to implement multiple function interfaces with the same signatures?

Practical use-case that I can think of: let's say you want to have a class that can handle Clickable and DoubleClickable, both would have something like `(Event) -> Unit`

**EDIT**: based on @mateusz's answer, this works, but only when using value classes, not if interface B and C are using normal Strings:

```
@JvmInline
value class BString(val value: String)

@JvmInline
value class CString(val value: String)

interface A {
    operator fun invoke()
}

interface B {
    operator fun invoke(something: BString)
}

interface C {
    operator fun invoke(somethingElse: CString)
}

class Test : A, B, C {

    override operator fun invoke() {
        println("invoke A")
    }

    override operator fun invoke(something: BString) {
        println("invoke B - something = $something")
    }

    override operator fun invoke(somethingElse: CString) {
        println("invoke C - somethingElse = $somethingElse")
    }

}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val handlerA = A::invoke
    val handlerB = B::invoke
    val handlerC = C::invoke

    val t = Test()

    handlerA(t) 
    handlerB(t, BString("hello B"))
    handlerC(t, CString("hello C"))

}
```

outputs:

> invoke A
>
> invoke B - something = BString(value=hello B)
>
> invoke C -somethingElse = CString(value=hello C)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The completer does not care about parameter's names.
The `fun test(a: String): String` and `fun test(b: String): String` are the same functions. When you will call `test("some")` then which function should be called?

You can create dedicated interfaces:

```kotlin
interface Clickable {
    fun click(param: String)
}

interface DoubleClickable {
    fun fastDoubleClick(param: String)
    fun slowDoubleClick(param: String)
}
```

Then you can use function references if you want `val handleClickFun: String -> Unit = Clickable::click`

Comment: handleClickFun(instanceOfTest, params), that's super neat!

Answer (score 1):

This will never work.  At the fundamental JVM level, you can't implement the same interface twice with different generics.  I would not expect this to *ever* work, even with the KEEP you mention.

Why do you want to extend function interfaces at all?  If you just want the nice call syntax, you can have separate `operator fun invoke` overloads, without overriding anything.  But even better would be using functions with actual names.  If you need to pass it to methods accepting lambdas, use method references, e.g. `Test::handleClick` and `Test::handleDoubleClick`.

Comment: I think the why is less important here than whether it's possible. I'm mostly exploring what's possible since I don't feel like I'm optimally using the functional parts of Kotlin. `A::invoke.invoke(t)` works, it's a pity I can't yet call A::invoke(t) or B::invoke(t, "some value")

Thanks for the input!

Comment: I wouldn't expect those ever to be added.  What do they add over `{ B.invoke(it, "some value") }` ?

Answer (score 1):

A typealias is just a way to give a convenient label to a specific type - it's not a type in itself, anywhere you specify that typealias, you can can just pass in a variable defined as the real type, or any other typealias you've derived from it.

So `B` and `C` are the same thing. You can have two different aliases for the same thing if that makes sense in different parts of your code (that's kinda the whole point of them! Relabel types to make them more readable or understandable) but that's just ways to *refer to* a type.

But when it comes to defining your class, it makes no sense. `B` and `C` are the same type, you're repeating yourself (and the compiler will give you a `supertype appears twice` error). And to implement that *one* type, you need *one* function - and *only* one, because if you have two identical functions then which one would get called?

So you can do this if you want:

```
typealias A = () -> Unit
typealias B = (something: String) -> Unit
typealias C = (somethingElse: String) -> Unit

class Test : A, B {

    override fun invoke() {
        println("invoke")
    }

    override fun invoke(something: String) {
        println("invoke: $something")
    }    
}

fun doAThing(thing: C) {
    thing("wow")
}


fun main() {
    doAThing(Test())
}
```

`doAThing` takes a `C`, so we can pass it a `B`, because `B` *is* `C`.

---

I'm guessing that's not very useful to you, but that's the limitation of typealiases, and bare function types in general. If you want two **separate** functions with the **exact same** signature in the same scope, you need to be able to refer to them *explicitly* - and that usually means giving them different names.

How is your click-handler class going to handle your `Event` if you can't tell it whether it's a single or double-click? And even if you could (e.g. through something like `(handlerFunction as B).invoke(event)`) then which of your identical overridden functions in the class is which?

Like *Mateusz* says, you need to use interfaces, and then you can pass references to the functions, because you have a name for each one you can refer to. The things you're passing those functions *into* can define the types using typealiases if they want. And if you want a type that can handle both kinds of clicks, create another interface that implements both types.

If you want to be able to pass a single object that has multiple functions with the same signature, that's what you need. If you want to use function types instead, you'll have to pass the individual function references in - but something somewhere has to be able to distinguish between them in the first place, and that's usually where they're defined

Comment: mateusz's sugestions allows me to do handleClickFun(instanceOfTest, params) which works great. It's a pity I can't yet do B::invoke(instanceOfTest, "param"), it says reserved for future use. B::invoke.invoke(instanceOfTest, "param") works, but it's not exactly pretty unless you hide it behind a typealias.

Thanks for the input!!

Comment: @JanVladimirMostert oh I didn't notice exactly what Mateusz had written, but I'd suggest passing `instanceOfTest::click` for the `handleClickFun` property instead - a reference to a function on the specific instance you want to use. Then you can just do `handleClickFun(params)`. You can make that property a bare function signature like `(String) -> Unit` and make a typealias for that if you like, and then it doesn't matter what you pass as long as it conforms to that type. Could be an anonymous lambda, could be a specific named function on an object - the use site doesn't need to know

Comment: The core problem is that if you have an interface that implements two things with identical functions, no matter how you're going to *use* them (say passing around references to those functions) you have to define an interface where you can call `invoke()` or whatever, and that means resolving that conflict. You can't have two of the same function, so you have to pick an implementation with `super<A>.invoke()` etc, or provide a new one. And I don't think there's a way to cast to `A` yourself and get the implementation defined there, like you can with a superclass. It's tricky!

Comment: I just noticed that I can do `val a = instanceOfTest::click` and then just do a("...") instead of `a(instanceOfTest, "...")` as you mentioned and I also read that the performance penalty for doing this is zero even though you're using KFunction which implies that you're using reflection.

Comment: @JanVladimirMostert it's not really doing reflection (and you don't have to import / add any reflection dependencies to use it) - if you decompile the Kotlin bytecode and look at the Java it's generating, it's basically creating a Java `Function` object that holds a reference to the instance, and exposes an `invoke` function that calls the relevant function on the instance. So there's no runtime reflection going on (that I'm aware of! I'm no expert on the language technicalities)